# How To Dynamically Enable Ripple Emulator with javascript or Jquery in Chrome without selecting platform

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ripple

I am generating a URL dynamically with .net, Now I am trying to load the URL with Ripple( Right Click --> Ripple --> Enable ). And Then I have to Select the Platform to render my URL in the device Mode. But My Requirement is, this process should be done with Javascript or jquery.

I tried with "MyDynamicallyURL?rippleenable=true" while generating URL. But it takes  long time to render and it doesn't load properly. I have to Manually reload the Page couple of times, then only it enables ripple and again i have to choose the paltform and again i have to reload the page until it renders the url with device mode.

can somebody Help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

http://emulate.phonegap.com/ Does exactly this. I don't know the mechanics of it, but that site was created to automatically enable Ripple and select the PhoneGap or Cordova platform.  You may be able to inspect the page to see what's going on.

Ripple has been significantly updated since you posted this question.  Some of the performance / stability concerns you mentioned may now be gone.